# simple URLSession uploadTask with progress bar

Tags: ios, swift, networking

i struggle totally with the URLSession and uploadTask. Actually I just want to upload a json to a Webserver and while the upload is in progress a simple progressbar should be shown. 
I implemented the approach given by apple: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/uploading_data_to_a_website

the upload is working and i get a response.. so far everything is fine but i don't know how i can show a during the upload a progress bar. What I tried is to show a progressbar before i call the method that contains the upload task

```
startActivityIndicator()

    let jsonPackage = JSONIncident(incident: incident)

    jsonPackage.sendToBackend(completion: {
        message, error in
  //Handle the server response




    })

    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
```

I realized that's stupid because the upload task works asynchronious in another thread.

I guess that i have to use Delegates but i don't know in which way. If i implement URLSessionTaskDelegate for example, i have to implement a bunch of functions like isProxy(), isKind(), isMember etc.

Could you please provide me a simple example how to show a progress bar during the uploadtask is working?
That would be so greate!
Thank you very much
regardsChris

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to conform to the URLSessionTaskDelegate protocol and call this delegate method:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didSendBodyData bytesSent: Int64, totalBytesSent: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToSend: Int64)
{
    let uploadProgress = Float(totalBytesSent) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToSend)
}
```

Then use the uploadProgress variable for your progress bar.

Create your session like this:

```
var session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
```

Comment: Hello adrgrondin, thanks for your help. I tried to conform the URLSessionTaskDelegate to my UITableViewController where i want to start the send process and where i want to show the progress bar. 
But when i try to conform that in the class that represents the json"package" what should be send, I get the error message: "..not conform to protocol NSObjectProtocol".
I guess that's because that the class is a simple swift class without any inheritances. It seems that i need a kind of extension or so for my UITableView Controller class to seperate the whole upload functionality.

Comment: You maybe need to make your class inherit NSObject. If you use the networking code directly in a UITableViewController and implement the protocol here you should not get this error.

Comment: Correct, `URLSessionTaskDelegate` conformants need to inherit from `NSObject` or implement a mess of annoying methods.

Answer (score -6):

You can use alamofire(for api calling) with swiftyJSON(json parsing) library for uploading JSON. You just have to call a loader before the alamofire api get called and stop the loader when you will get the response.

Comment: HI Jatin, thanks for your help. The problem is, it's not allowed to use external libraries that are not approved :( But i will take a look in that libraries. Thank you

Comment: Doesn't answer the question and 'just use alamofire' is an overused solution to basic netowrking problems. unless you have an explicit reason, don't just blindly import this dependency, as good as it might be.

Comment: This is how we say "welcome" on SO? <<facepalm>>